# How to update an existing AWS AppConfig profile data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config

Lets say I have a Hosted configuration version in my app config:

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "A": 1,
      "B": 2
    },
    {
      "C": 3,
      "D": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to update this version to newer one :

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "A": 1,
      "B": 2
    },
    {
      "C": 3,
      "D": 4
    },
    {
      "E": 5,
      "F": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

How can we achieve this?
As far as the documentation we can use `CreateHostedConfigurationVersion` to create a new version but can't update an existing one. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create it again:

```bash
content=$(cat foo.json | base64)

aws appconfig create-hosted-configuration-version \
  --application-id APPID \
  --configuration-profile-id PROFILEID \
  --content $content \
  --content-type application/json \
  out.json
```

The new version of AppConfig profile will be created.